# Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton

Tags: android, user-interface, button, google-play

I have a button of Google Sign-in, and I don't know how fix it :(

the error is when pass `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);` the class is a Activity and implements this:

```
  public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, Responser<User>,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

I don't know where is the error, but after it was okay :(, could somebody help me please?

### This is the Gradles

## app:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.iesnervion.qa"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        //AÑADIDO PARA JAVA 8
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        lease {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    //For CardViews and RecyclerViews
    //Retrofit
    //For animations


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
    compile 'org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(path: ':libraries:BaseGameUtils')

}
```

## BaseGameUtils

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('appcompat_library_version')) {
        ext.appcompat_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('support_library_version')) {
        ext.support_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('gms_library_version')) {
        ext.gms_library_version = '8.4.0'
    }

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:${gms_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${gms_library_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${gms_library_version}"
}

android {
    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_compile_version')) {
        ext.android_compile_version = 23
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_min_version')) {
        ext.android_min_version = 15
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_version')) {
        ext.build_tools_version = "23.0.2"
    }

    // Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
    if (!project.hasProperty('android_min_sdk_version')) {
        ext.android_min_sdk_version = 9
    }

    compileSdkVersion android_compile_version
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion android_min_version
        targetSdkVersion android_compile_version
    }
}
```

### Activity login

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/loginId"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    tools:context="es.iesnervion.qa.ui.View.LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:maxHeight="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_big"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/prueba">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:minLines="1" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Ó"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <!-- sign-in button -->
            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/google_sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: es.iesnervion.qa, PID: 5133
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.iesnervion.qa/es.iesnervion.qa.ui.View.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                                                                    at es.iesnervion.qa.ui.View.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:116)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:657)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                                                                    at es.iesnervion.qa.ui.View.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:116) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631)
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                                                                    at es.iesnervion.qa.ui.View.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:116) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzac(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/zzd; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamic/zze; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zze' appears in /data/app/es.iesnervion.qa-1/base.apk)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzae.zzc(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzae.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.zzbw(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.setStyle(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:631) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                                                                    at es.iesnervion.qa.ui.View.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:116) 
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: did u try gradle sync

Comment: yeess :(, I will try to restar android studio invalidating the cache :/

Comment: same issue, it's impossible :(, Could be for this  `mavenCentral()` ?

Comment: same problem but only on huawei device

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that Google's Maven repository is included in your project's top-level build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must instead use:
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
    }
}
```

Then declare Google Play services as a dependency, in your app-level build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    ...

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    }
```

**PS:**Avoid declaring multiple versions of play services dependencies, this can cause mismatches and consequently generate the bug you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

Just include `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'` dependency in your build.gradle(app).

Answer (score 0):

You must include    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'    for google sign in. Because the google-sign in button is used for Google sign purpose. So you should include the dependency for it in your gradle file(app)